# Why RAM works on lower frequency?

Tags: memory, cpu-z

Notebook `Samsung RC510 (NP-RC510-S01PL)`
I have `2x2GB Samsung RAM` memory, that are able to work with `633MHz` (`PC3-10600S`). But when I check with CPU-Z I see they are works on `533 Mhz`. Notebook is new, RAM factory default likewise. 
Have you anu idea?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the memory controller on the CPU does not support speeds above 533MHz (1066MHz DDR)

I believe your laptop has a Core i3 CPU which has that limit:
http://ark.intel.com/products/50178/

Comment: Yes, I agree with the above part. Also maybe the BIOS is recognizing the Default SPD speed (1066MHz) rather than the rated speed (1333MHz). Sometimes the BIOS may have an option to adjust the memory speed manually so check it.